# jQuery to move a box adjacent to the current target anchor position

Tags: jquery, anchor, dom-traversal

On this page > http://canvas.clickbump.com/example/

I've got a floating "Table of Contents" box which has hyperlinks that target a couple of hidden anchor elements on the page:

```
<a id="anchor1">This is anchor 1</a>
```

And

```
<a id="anchor2">This is anchor 2</a>
```

The markup of the box:

```
<details class="cb-toc" open="open">
    <summary>Table of Contents</summary>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#top">GoTo Top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#anchor1">GoTo Anchor 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#anchor2">GoTo Anchor 2</a></li>
    </ol>
</details>
```

I'm trying to use the jQuery script below in order to bind the clicks on the TOC's links so that it moves the floating box to the position adjacent to the target anchor. However, its hit or miss. Takes two clicks on the anchor to move the box to the proper position.

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
jQuery('.cb-toc a').on('click',foo);
function foo(){
    jQuery('a:target').after(jQuery('.cb-toc'));
}
```

Any ideas what can do to get it to move the box to the proper position on the first click every time?

Comment: Seems like your page is reloaded when you click the link.

Comment: Just fixed that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: FYI you should use the .on function as opposed to .bind. From what I've read just now, the all event handling will be done through .on in the coming versions of js. The parameters are the same between bind and on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually select the correct anchor:

```
jQuery('.cb-toc a').click(function(e){
    var str = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery(str).after(jQuery('.cb-toc'));
}
```

Comment: 1. If you are preventing the default, the anchor won't do it's job. 2. IDs are used (you know, for the hash to work), not classes, so you can keep the `#` and leave out the `a.`

Comment: True, thanks. Updated solution. Hadn't linked one and one together. derp.

Comment: Fixed the variable calling. Try it now. Are you catching any errors in your js console?

Comment: @user751564 Now it's basically the same as my solution :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa not intended :)

Comment: @user751564 :). One good point is that through using jQuery's `attr` instead of the DOM property I tried makes it return the real value, which should be the simple hash. The browser updates the property with the full URL for me. Using `this.hash` seems to be the cleanest way though if it has no cross-browser issues, but won't research on this now...

Comment: didn't know about the hash property in jquery. but good to know, i'll be using it from now on, thanks.

Comment: @user751564 It is not a jQuery property, it's native DOM.

Answer (score 2):

When your click handler runs, the new target is not set yet, it will happen afterwards. That is why the TOC always positions itself next to the previous target (working fine after two clicks on the same link).

You could either use `setTimeout()` to delay execution of the TOC placement, or listen to the `onhashchange` event that is fired when the browser sets the new target. Or you can simply give up the `:target` approach and locate the right anchor yourself, something like:

```
function foo() {
     //hash will be something like #top
     var hash = this.hash;

     //wait, it looks like an ID selector :)
     jQuery(hash).after(jQuery('.cb-toc'));
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7e662/)

Some work might need to be done, so the `hash` variable always holds the right value in every browser (`#whatever`), so this example is not production-ready code, just an illustration.